# BlackberryLocationProvider setLocationListener does not give periodic location updates on 8900, on rest of the devices works fine

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

I am currently working on a location based solution where I need to process periodic location updates. It works fine on Torch 9800, Bold 9780, however, does not give me periodic location updates on Curve 8900 with OS 5.0.0.535.

I have defined my criteria as:

```
bbCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria();
bbCriteria.setSpeedAndCourseRequired(false);
bbCriteria.setCostAllowed(true);
if(bbCriteria.getMode() == GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST) {
    bbCriteria.setHorizontalAccuracy(20);
    bbCriteria.setVerticalAccuracy(20);
}
```

and I am registering for periodic updates by:

```
locationProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider)LocationProvider.getInstance(bbCriteria);
locationProvider.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener(), getUpdateInterval(), -1, -1);
```

where I do calculate time interval on basis of my business logic. In general it is 60 seconds.

I do receive periodic location updates in my listener for a number of devices for example Torch 9800, Bold 9780 however on Curve 9800 after first update nothing happens.

Moreover, default GPS mode in other devices is ASSISTED, however, on Curve 8900 it is AUTONOMOUS.

Please let me know what the issue can be?

Answer (score 2):

Well... What I have found from my testing is that the LocationListener seems to only *listen* for location but not actually request it. So if another app requests the location, your app will get it periodically, but if nothing is actively asking for a location - none will be given. The solution I have implemented is to completely abandon the LocationListener and simply set a timer that calls getLocation periodically to get the new location. This works fine across the board. This method also gives you more control since if the device failed to get a location you will know and get the reason (timeout etc.).

As for your question regarding the default, different devices may have different defaults also based on the carrier. So for example Verizon really limits the support for Assisted and Cellsite.